# Using JQuery to embed an external HTML file

Tags: jquery, html, import

I am working on a page that needs to import one HTML file into another using JQuery's "load" command. It should be fairly simple - it pulls in the content of the site header (logo image, search box, menu bar).

On my test page it works, but in the live storefront it doesn't work, and I can't figure out why.

Here's the line in my JS file - very simple:

```
$("#x-head").load('http://www.sunandfuninoc.com/testingsites/jxinstalls/topparts/ebay/head.html');
```

The HTML div that should be populating looks like this on my main page:

Here's the test page that's working brilliantly:
http://www.sunandfuninoc.com/testingsites/jxinstalls/topparts/ebay/store.html

Here's the live site that's not loading at all:
http://stores.ebay.com/Top-Parts-Store

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console or Firebug or whatever developer tools you are using in your browser?

Comment: "Origin http://stores.ebay.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: No errors in Firebug or Chrome show in the JS, no.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the same origin policy that JavaScript operates under.

Except where servers expressly permit it, you may not pull content from a separate, remote server (i.e. other than the one you're running on) when using AJAX.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Unless the server you are calling allows cross-domain calling, your only option will be to load the page not via jQuery but via a server-side proxy, e.g. PHP via [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). Server-side languages are not normally subject to this restriction.

Comment: Ok so does that mean that it's disabled because it's on an eBay.com site? Is there any way around this?

Comment: I mean is there another type of script or another function that will do the same thing?

Comment: No - it's a default policy, it's not specifically about eBay. Check out the link I provided re: SOP. Unless the target *expressly* allows calling over cross-domain AJAX, you will not be able to do it. Re: your second comment, no - as I say, it's a policy governing all of client-side programming, not a limitation specific to jQuery or the function you're using.

Answer (score 1):

It works in the first case since the request you are making is on the same domain as the website it is hosted on. In the second case, `store.ebay.com` is making the request, and due to security features in modern browsers, that cross domain request is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** `load();` will work if the url you are using is under the same domain.

**2.** If you want to load external content like `store.ebay.com` use a proxy, if you are using PHP you can make a PHP file that gets the source from that site using cURL. Otherwise you won't be able to achieve what you want cause of `Access-Controll-Allow-Origin` rule (that means that you can load external content that is not in your domain).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into the PHP option for sure.

Comment: Just to know, this is the way to use the proxy, check this out: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html